# Can SSRS SQL Reports have the Crystal option of exporting to "Excel (Data Only)"?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, crystal-reports, report

We are migrating from Crystal Reports to SQL Server Reports (SSRS). I noticed in the Export options of SQL Reports there is no way to export **Data Only** like there is in Crystal. Googling proved fruitless - I found an old article implying that it was not in SSRS:

http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/SSRSandCR_Exporting.asp

I found a 3rd party control which appears to do something similar but I need to know if this is possible natively?
http://www.aspose.com/categories/ssrs-rendering-extensions/aspose.total-for-reporting-services/default.aspx

Comment: Can you not export as CSV, and open that in Excel?

Comment: When you say export as CSV - do you mean as Excel and rename the file to .csv? This is what I tried and it opened just like an excel file (ie. not data only)

Comment: @JamieF: I think my memory must have been at fault.

Comment: @Rodney No, don't simply rename. You should be able to export directly from SSRS to .csv http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154606%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: I want to congratulate you on the move from Crystal to Reporting Services.  That is a very good move.

Answer (score 1):

I'll move Steven's comment down to an answer. Exporting to .CSV or XML should be good data export formats

2005 formats on up to 2008 all include .csv
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154606%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Both CSV and xml export formats were designed to handle this.

If you want some of the formatting, but not all of it, then look at creating customr versions of the report for export or using the RenderFormat available in 2008R2:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2010/05/02/globals-renderformat-aka-renderer-dependent-report-layout.aspx